# How to pull the javascript off of a page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, `element.html()` will retrieve the html of an element.

If within a div there is `<script> //code </script>` is there a way to get the html and javascript that was written there prior to being processed by the browser.

Something like: `element.htmlAndScripts()`

edit: sorry let me illustrate:

```
<div id='1'>
    <script>alert('hello');</script>
</div>


$('document').ready(function(){
   var content = $('#1').html();
   alert(content);
});


//how to make content = 
//"<script>alert('hello');</script>" ?
```

Comment: *prior to being processed by the browser* If it is already in the DOM it would be processed bty the time you can read it...

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually using `.html()` is the right way to do this. It being processed by the browser (*ran*), is not going to change the script. If we used `.text()` it does not give the `<script>` tags, while `.html()` does. For example if we had the following HTML:

```
<div id="t">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <script> alert("Hello World"); </script>
</div>
```

Doing `$("#t").html()` gives us the output:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
<script> alert("Hello World"); </script>
```

While `$("#t").text()` gives us the output:

```
Hello World
 alert("Hello World");
```

Comment: Still confused on what OP was after when what was posted in the question should have returned the script tag. lol

Answer (score 1):

Maybe .text() would be more appropriate since you want to get plain text

```
element.text() or element.innerText;
```

Comment: I highly doubt this is what the OP wants.

Comment: This is what i understand from his question

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can use:

```
$("script").text()
```